# Back Button to close app

Tags: android

I have a splash screen which leads into a main navigational screen which has animations in it to introduce the buttons. Want I want is to close the app when the back button is pressed. It currently reloads the activity (main) when the return button is called - why is this?

I looked about on the forums and one way was to use the finish() method. I tried implementing this in the main.java class like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) 
    {     
        this.finish();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the above didn't do it - what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

UPDATE

Cheers all for swift reply but none of these works. But I think I may know why - my class only implements the onCreate() method and none others. Could this be why all the other methods are failing?

UPDATE

Hi - I sorted it but I don't, at this moment, understand why this works & the other methods don't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0 ) 
    {
        // do something on back.
        moveTaskToBack( true );
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

So why would this work and the finish() method used in the onBackPressed() demonstrated by ekawas doesn't??

Answer (score 1):

[onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) is probably getting the keydown event before your onKeyDown is.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this, I would call from the splash screen activity a [startActivityForResults](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Return a boolean that tells the activity to quit, and then finish the base activity.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `finish` in the splash screen Activity after calling `startActivity`, then try this in your `onKeyDown`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
            finish();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@overide
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
   return;
}
```

Do that in your activity rather than listening for key presses.